# Mistakenly setup a Time Machine disk, how to recover the data?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, time-machine

I have a NTFS external disk used by a Windows PC and there were lots of important data on it.

My friend took the disk and plugged in to my Mac just now and mistakenly setup it as a Time Machine backup disk. Now the disk is erased and I'm wondering is there any way that I can recover my original data?

Answer (score 3):

Tell your friend to load the backup.

If he has none tell him to bite the loss and learn the lesson to have backups.

Alternatively, if nothing has been stored, the old file system may still be mostly on the disc. Any data recovery company may be helpful – for a larger 4 digit USD amount. Maybe 5 digit. If the data is TRULY important, that is not too much money.